# Pandas: convert different datatypes to pyarrow datatypes using astype()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with different datatypes like bool, int, float, datetime, category.
currently I am converting

```
# Earlier to pandas 2.0

1. object -> string
2. object -> datetime[ns] # if date
```

With new pandas 2.0 or above, I am trying to use pyarrow datatypes for all fields and saving in `parquet` format.

We can have below:

```
int8 -> int8[pyarrow] likewise for other int's type
float16 -> float16[pyarrow] likewise for other float's type
string or object -> string[pyarrow]

eg:

df['col_int'] = df['col_int'].astype('int8[pyarrow]')
```

I did not find much on how to convert datetime and category using `astype()` for below:

```
1. datetime -> timestamp # if date
2. category -> dictionary

eg:

df['col_date'] = df['col_date'].astype(???)
df['col_dictionary'] = df['col_dictionary'].astype(???)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyarrow as pa

df['col_date'] = df['col_date'].astype(pd.ArrowDtype(pa.string()))
```

More [apache arrow data types](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/data.html)